# Finding a maximum XOR match

Tags: math, binary

I need yo find a number of given series that has maximum XOR with a given constant number. Suppose like this:
Given Series: 
6 7 8 9 10
and the given constant number is 10. The maximum XOR for 10 with other given numbers is 13, which is for 7. So I need to find 7.
Now i am following the standard approach. The problem is when I am given 100000 integers, my code is eating up so much of time. Is there any other way to find this out efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I can think of doing this is to loop through your array of numbers and XOR them with your constant, finding the maximum as you go by comparing them with the largest you've previously found. After finding the largest number just XOR it with your constant again to find the original value.

Java Code:

```
public int findMaximumXOR(int[] nums, int constantNum)
{
    int largest = nums[0] ^ constantNum;
    for (int i = 1; i<nums.length; ++i)
        if (largest<(nums[i] ^ constantNum))
            largest = (nums[i] ^ constantNum);

    return (largest ^ constantNum);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can find directly 7(in my question)? Any algorithm that reduces the complexity? I am able to do only one test case in 5 secs with this code.

Comment: Is the series of numbers always sequential or is the series read in or generated randomly? Because if there is no order to the series then I think this is the fastest way to do it, since you must loop through the array.

Comment: No, sorting would make it worse, since when you sort you're doing a bunch of comparisons between the numbers in the array. If you're reading in these numbers then you could potentially skip the array and just compare them to largest as you read them in, but I don't think that would help a whole lot.

Comment: http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_cs;action=display;num=1259478132
Theres something related to XOR maximum pairs here. But I did not understood that..take a look.

Comment: It looks like the solutions on that page is for a slightly different problem than you posed. In their problem you are given an array of random numbers and must find the two that when XOR'd together give you the largest value. So you could apply their solution, which seemed to revolve around using binary trees, to your problem but it would over-complicate it and end up being less efficient because in the process of building the tree you are again making a lot of comparisons and essentially sorting things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6715/discussion-between-sans481-and-aoi222)

Answer (score 0):

Let `a` be the array and `q` be the number.

You sort the given array first and then perform binary search for the `(MAX-q)` where `MAX` is the maximum possible integer (2<sup>31</sup>-1). The idea is that the exor is maximum when all the bits are opposite of those in number `q`.

Comment: what if i don't find (MAX-q)?

Comment: even if MAX-q does not exist in the array its not a issue, we just need its position in array

Answer (score 0):

```
int L = 0, R = n-1;
for(int i = 31; i >= 0 && L < R; i--) {
  if(((a[L]>>i)&1) == ((a[R]>>i)&1))
    continue;
  int l = L, r = R;
  while(r - l > 1) {
    int m = (r+l)/2;
    if((a[m]>>i)&1) r = m;
    else l = m;
  }
  if((b>>i)&1) R = l;
  else L = r;
}
```

`L` is the index of the number which maximizes xor with number `b` while
`a` contains the number in sorted order

Answer (score 0):

One can use a tree here.

Construct a binary tree as you input the numbers, with MSB on the top.

Now for each number eg 1011 traverse the tree for 0100...

At any point if the ideal compliment is not found compromise for whatever is available and continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int l = in.nextInt();
        int r = in.nextInt();

        String ls = Integer.toBinaryString(l);
        String rs = Integer.toBinaryString(r);

        if (ls.length() != rs.length()) {
            System.out.println((int)Math.pow(2, rs.length())-1);        
            return;
        }

        int len = ls.length();      
        int index=0;

        for(; index < len; ++index){
            if (ls.charAt(index) != rs.charAt(index))
                break;
        }

        if (index == len) //l = r
            System.out.println(0);
        else
            System.out.println((int)Math.pow(2, len-index)-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how does this solution solve the above problem. can you please explain ?